# How to get a list of members of a social circle from list of pairs of acquaintances in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, social-networking, graph-theory

I'm working on a problem that has been framed in the context of the beginning of a social network when less connections exist. A time when there are still many pairs of people without any path connecting them. I have a list of pairs of people who know each other directly, that is have a first order connection let's say, and using this table I want to get a table listing the groups of people that have some connection to each other (not necessarily first order).

So for example the table of first order connections might look like:

[image: [1]]

From this we can conclude that the following groups of connected people exist:

[image: [2]]

I am attempting to do this in SQL (MySQL) which I am finding quite tricky (as in struggling to even start, I'm a complete SQL novice and have only ever worked in R). I have played around with the basic functions and ordered the lists and grouped by etc but I'm stumped. Any help or suggestion to get going would be much appreciated.

Apologies if I have abused any graph theory terminology and for the slightly shoddy tables!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I'm pretty sure the answer is Bill, Ringo,... and Ronnie.

Comment: It looks to me like you want to find [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) in the undirected graph created by the given connections.

Do you really need to stick to SQL or would it be possible to move to a more procedural programming language (C++, Python, Java, even R)? The simplest solution I know of would be about 20 lines in any of the above mentioned languages, but a lot more than that in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah sticking to SQL is part of the challenge (unfortuantely!). I still keep thinking in procedural language terms though; Taking each element of a row and looping through the rest of the rows to find a match seemed like a simple starting point. Several cross joins and left joins on various matching conditions was the SQL equivalent that I came up with. It's quite brute force and inefficient but it has allowed me to correctly find some of the connected groups.